# NullPointerException when trying to get element from store

Tags: java, arrays, swing, nullpointerexception, settext

I have a swing application with the following classes:
ControllerGUI: loads my mainform
Date: used to convert numbers from input into date format
Employee: extends person class and sets variables like salary, job title
MainForm: swing gui
Person: sets variables for other details like name, gender, dob 
Store: Holds the array Employee[] list;

I have a displayInformation JPanel where I want to display the name, salary, job title etc in JTextFields from the store and then allow the user to browse the entries with next and previous buttons. However I'm hitting a NullPointerException when trying to get it to work in the first place.

In my MainForm I add a new Store

```
Store testStore = new Store(100);
```

I want the elements in the array to be outputed to different JTextFields like:

```
showName.setText(testStore.list[listIndex].name);
```

(where listIndex is an int I initiated)
but from that I am getting a NullPointerException, the error goes away if I take off the .name or .salary whatever I want to get, but then obviously there's no point in the code anyway.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

```
 public class Store implements Serializable {
    private static int MAXSIZE; // holds the size of the array
    private static int count; // keeps count of number of persons stored in
                                // array

    Employee[] list; // array for storing person objects

    public Store(int size) {
        list = new Employee[size];
        MAXSIZE = size;
        count = 0;
    }
```

Comment: We need to see how the list is initialised, are you expecting there to be a valid employee at that element of the array?

Comment: added the code to the bottom of my post. all I want to do is after an employee has been added, for the user to be able to view the details in a separate JPanel, so load each detail (name, dob etc) from the array into a textfield.

So of course when the program starts the array is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because:

```
testStore.list[listIndex]
```

is null.

You can use:

```
showName.setText(testStore.list[listIndex] == null ? null : testStore.list[listIndex].name);
```

Actually, a lot better approach is to use setters and getters in Person class, and then use:

```
testStore.list[listIndex].getName()
```

To get the Person's name.

Comment: We can be pretty sure that variable is null by this "the error goes away if I take off the .name or .salary whatever I want to get, but then obviously there's no point in the code anyway.". Sadly this doesnt really answer his question

Comment: yes it is null.

Oh and just to add I get this error even if I do this in my person class and initialise the variable (before it is via data entry in the gui)

protected String name = "blah";

Comment: @cowls its hard to know what exactly is the question, but I've added a solution. Thanx for clarifying!

Comment: Much better, at least now there is a possible solution :). I suspect this isnt the root cause though

Comment: Thanks @baraky but for some reason that isn't working either. The first bit of code you suggested does nothing, the textfield is just empty.

The second bit of code, even though I do have setters and getters in my Person class, still gives me the NullPointerException.

Comment: @baraky sorry I've got it working, had to switch some code around. Thanks for the help! I'd vote up your answer if I could :)